# Why are the changes I make to my Rust program from VS Code not reflected when I compile?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I'm having a problem with Rust that I strongly suspect has do with a disconnect between Cargo and VS Code.

- I build my Cargo project with `cargo new project`
- I edit my *src/main.rs* with VS Code and save it.
- I issue `cargo run`
- I see the result from the hello world *main.rs* instead of the results of the changes I made.

What I find interesting is that if I do a `cat src/main.rs` from the terminal, I see the original Rust code, even though VS Code assures me that it saved it and shows me that code even if I restart VS Code.

I've had this problem on a couple of computers now (same OS, Fedora 28).  I strongly suspect that Cargo is doing some buffering somewhere that is defeating VS Code.  Has anyone else seen this behavior or know the cause?  Are there any cures or work-arounds?

Comment: try using another code editing software, e.g. Notepad++.  if the problem goes away, then there may be a problem with VSCode

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for [the forum](https://users.rust-lang.org), because this question does not relate to programming (IMHO).

Comment: I strongly suspect you are not editing the file you think you are. Or you are calling cargo run from the wrong directory.

Comment: @hellow Questions regarding the use of an IDE for programming purposes are considered on-topic for SO. The only possible issue in this question is that we might not be able to reproduce it.

Comment: That's a good idea, Tau.  I'll give that a try and post back the results.  My main issue is I really love VS Code and as a newbie to Rust, I'm not sure what I would do.  Thanks!

Comment: That's the first thing I thought of, Benjamin Lindley, but I've double and triple checked and more and I can state 100% that that's not the problem.  Thanks though.

Comment: I'd love to know if anyone gets the same or different results using Cargo and VS Code, regardless of OS, E_Net4.  Since I had the same results on two different computers, although both are running Fedora 28, it would about have to be the OS.

Comment: VSCode works fine with the exact same steps on macOS. I doubly agree that your VS Code isn't saving to the same directory that your cargo process is in.

Comment: The fact that `cargo run` seems to be executing the code that is displayed by `cat src/main.rs` sheds doubt on your theory that cargo has anything to do with the problem. And FWIW, I also use VSCode (on Windows), and do not have this problem.

Comment: @Tigger Note that you have to mention the user with the `@` prefix in order for that user to receive a notification. As for this issue, consider also including all details on how (and from where) you installed Rust+Cargo and Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

@Tau turned out to be correct.  Using Kwrite, the changes seemed to propagate correctly.  What's really odd is that Kwrite and VS Code seemed to synchronize with one another.  That's really annoying for me as I am a VS Code fanatic.  Maybe I post an issue about this for VS Code.  Thanks to all for their suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how, But, there were two `main.rs` files got created. I was changing the first one, but rust was compiling the other one.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure autosave is enabled in VSCode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).